# Can't get setInterval to work properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, sheetrock

I'm inputting data to Google Spreadsheets, publishing it to the web and loading it into a table using a jQuery plugin called [Sheetrock](https://github.com/chriszarate/sheetrock), all of which works well. But I'm trying to use 'setInterval' so as to reload the data every few seconds but I can't get it to work; the table takes 3 seconds to load initially but then never reloads again.

Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/thekingsrook/F78bG/) of the example I've been working with, and the setInterval code I've added is below, thanks for reading.

```
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        setInterval(function() {
            $('#statistics').sheetrock({
              url: mySpreadsheet,
            }) 
        }, 3000);
    });
```

Comment: In fiddle error is `Access denied `

Comment: What does the console say?

Comment: Your setInterval works fine...you have error on ` $('#statistics').sheetrock({
              url: mySpreadsheet,
            }) ` check it properly!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do alter on you code : check it :

```
  $( document ).ready(function() {
      setInterval(function() {
           $('#statistics').load(mySpreadsheet)
        }, 3000);
    });
```

[**Working DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ashish41191/t3WYx/3/)

Comment: I suggest you to not use `setInterval` because your table is automatically updated in every 5 minutes.

Comment: Thanks Ashish it's reloading now. And yes I just saw that now, does Google Spreadsheets update itself? Maybe there's an option to change it...

Comment: Upon further review, it seems that setInterval isn't updating the data, the changes that I make in the Google Spreadsheet will only show up after 5 minutes, despite the setInterval being 3000ms.

Comment: I think you're right, while the Spreadsheet is saved straight away, the published version is not updated as fast.